# Codeigniter 4 - How to run one specific migration file?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have a project with multiple migration files, according to different modules of the project. I want to pass a key (associative array) and run all the files on that index.

```
//EXAMPLE

$files = [
    'blog' => [
        //array of file names
    ],
    'storage' => [
        //array of file names
    ],
    'sales' => [
        //array of file names
    ],
]

runAll($files['sales'])
```

I've read the [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/migration.html) but it just allow specified class name in terminal.

Edit: Just checked again and it either allow class name but namespace on migrate command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate a single file regardless of order or batches using the [method `force(string $path, string $namespace, ?string $group = null)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/048d9973029803471f73d489bb418729587e1244/system/Database/MigrationRunner.php#L329) available within the [`MigrationRunner` class](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Database/MigrationRunner.php).

[force($path, $namespace, $group)](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/dbmgmt/migration.html#force)

> This forces a single file to migrate regardless of order or batches.
> Method “up” or “down” is detected based on whether it has already been
> migrated.
>
> **Note:**
>
> This method is recommended only for testing and could cause data
> consistency issues.

So in your case, you would just run a `for` loop through the files as you pass the expected parameters in the `force(...)` method. I.e:

Assuming the array keys of your `$files` array represent the various *'modules'* of the project:

```php
$migrate = \Config\Services::migrations();
$psr4 = config(\Config\Autoload::class)->psr4;

foreach ($files as $module => $filenames) {

    $namespace = "Modules\\" . ucwords($module);

    foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
        try {
            $migrate->force($psr4[$namespace] . "\\" . $filename, $namespace);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Do something with the error here...
        }
    }
}
```

##### NOTES:

The above solution assumes that you already mapped your `$psr4` namespaces in your application modules to their respective locations on the file system: I.e:

File: **app/Config/Autoload.php**

```php
// ...

    public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config' => APPPATH . 'Config',
        'Modules\Blog' => ROOTPATH . 'module/blog',
        'Modules\Storage' => ROOTPATH . 'module/storage',
        'Modules\Sales' => ROOTPATH . 'module/sales',
    ];

// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For those coming here wondering how to *run one specific migration file* in Codeigniter 4:

Unfortunately, at the time of writing this post, I couldn't find a direct command/way to handle this task.

Luckily, you can have access to the methods available within the [`MigrationRunner` class](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Database/MigrationRunner.php) in your own source code.

[Usage Example Here](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/dbmgmt/migration.html#usage-example)

Even better, you have the ability to [create your own custom commands](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/cli/cli_commands.html#id4).

With that in mind, I created a custom command to support running a *single migration file*.

##### Custom Command

Step 1:
Generate the basic command file by running the command below in your terminal:

```sh
php spark make:command MigrateFile --command migrate:file --group Database --suffix Command
```

This will create/generate a command file in the path: **APPPATH\Commands\MigrateFileCommand.php**

Step 2:
Edit this new command file (*app/Commands/MigrateFileCommand.php*) to something similar to the source code below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Commands;

use CodeIgniter\CLI\BaseCommand;
use CodeIgniter\CLI\CLI;
use Config\Services;

class MigrateFileCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * The Command's Group
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $group = 'Database';

    /**
     * The Command's Name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'migrate:file';

    /**
     * The Command's Description
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Migrates a single migration file.';

    /**
     * The Command's Usage
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $usage = 'migrate:file [arguments] [options]';

    /**
     * The Command's Arguments
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $arguments = [
        'name' => 'The valid migration file path beginning from the ROOTPATH. For example: php spark migrate:file "app\Database\Migrations\2022-02-16-101819_AddBlogMigration.php"'
    ];

    /**
     * The Command's Options
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options = [
        '--namespace' => 'Set migration namespace. Default: "App".',
        '--dbgroup' => 'Set database group. Default: "default".',
    ];

    /**
     * Actually execute a command.
     *
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function run(array $params)
    {
        CLI::write("Running migration...", 'yellow');

        $message = "";
        $paramsSize = count($params);

        if (!$paramsSize) {
            $message = 'Too few arguments passed. Missing "migration file path."';
        } else if ($paramsSize > 1) {
            $message = 'Too many arguments passed.';
        }

        if ($paramsSize !== 1) {
            CLI::write(sprintf('Invalid Params: %s', $message), 'red');
            CLI::newLine();
            $this->showHelp();
            return;
        }

        $runner = Services::migrations();
        $namespace = ($params['namespace'] ?? CLI::getOption('namespace')) ?: "App";
        $dbgroup = ($params['dbgroup'] ?? CLI::getOption('dbgroup')) ?: "default";

        try {
            if (!$runner->force(ROOTPATH . $params[0], $namespace, $dbgroup)) {
                CLI::error(lang('Migrations.generalFault'), 'light_gray', 'red'); // @codeCoverageIgnore
            }

            $messages = $runner->getCliMessages();

            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                CLI::write($message);
            }

            CLI::write('Done migration.', 'green');

            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->showError($e);
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
        }
    }
}
```

The source code above is essentially making use of the [`force(...)` method](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/dbmgmt/migration.html#force) to execute a single migration file.

Step 3:
Now moving forward, you can easily run a single migration file using the command below in your terminal.

```sh
 php spark migrate:file "app\Database\Migrations\2022-02-16-101819_AddBlogMigration.php"
```

*Sample Output:*

```sh
CodeIgniter v4.1.4 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2022-02-16 13:09:34 UTC+01:00

Running migration...
        Running: (App) 2022-02-16-101819_App\Database\Migrations\AddBlogMigration
Done migration.
```

If in case your migration file resides in a different namespace other than `App`, for example in a different module (*'Modules\Sales'*), you can pass an option defining the specific namespace.
The command also supports passing a different database group other than *'default'*. I.e:

```sh
php spark migrate:file "app\Database\Migrations\2022-02-16-101819_AddBlogMigration.php" --namespace "Modules\Sales" --dbgroup "tests"
```

You can view the documentation of the new command by running the command below:

```sh
php spark help migrate:file
```

*Sample Output:*

```sh
CodeIgniter v4.1.4 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2022-02-16 15:16:31 UTC+01:00

Usage:
  migrate:file [arguments] [options]

Description:
  Migrates a single migration file.

Arguments:
  name  The valid migration file path beginning from the ROOTPATH. For example: php spark migrate:file "app\Database\Migrations\2022-02-16-101819_AddBlogMigration.php"

Options:
  --namespace  Set migration namespace. Default: "App".
  --dbgroup    Set database group. Default: "default".
```

##### Bonus Tip

If for some reason you wish to [run the new command from within your own code](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/cli/cli_commands.html#calling-commands) or Controller, this is possible by using:

```php
echo command('migrate:file "app\Database\Migrations\2022-02-16-101819_AddBlogMigration.php"');
```

Comment: Even if this is not the answer to my problem, this is a must-to-know

Answer (score 0):

let's do it  like me,
see codes step by  step

this  my codes modules

in app/config/autoload.php

````
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\AutoloadConfig;

/**
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * AUTOLOADER CONFIGURATION
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This file defines the namespaces and class maps so the Autoloader
 * can find the files as needed.
 *
 * NOTE: If you use an identical key in $psr4 or $classmap, then
 * the values in this file will overwrite the framework's values.
 */
class Autoload extends AutoloadConfig
{
    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Namespaces
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This maps the locations of any namespaces in your application to
     * their location on the file system. These are used by the autoloader
     * to locate files the first time they have been instantiated.
     *
     * The '/app' and '/system' directories are already mapped for you.
     * you may change the name of the 'App' namespace if you wish,
     * but this should be done prior to creating any namespaced classes,
     * else you will need to modify all of those classes for this to work.
     *
     * Prototype:
     *```
     *   $psr4 = [
     *       'CodeIgniter' => SYSTEMPATH,
     *       'App'         => APPPATH
     *   ];
     *```
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
        'Myth\Auth'   => APPPATH .'ThirdParty/myth-auth/src',
        'Modules\Shared' => ROOTPATH . 'module/shared',
        'Modules\Common' => ROOTPATH . 'module/common',
        'Modules\Auth' => ROOTPATH . 'module/auth',
        'Modules\Home' => ROOTPATH . 'module/home',
        'Modules\Payment' => ROOTPATH . 'module/payment',
        'Modules\App' => ROOTPATH . 'module/app',
    ];

    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Class Map
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * The class map provides a map of class names and their exact
     * location on the drive. Classes loaded in this manner will have
     * slightly faster performance because they will not have to be
     * searched for within one or more directories as they would if they
     * were being autoloaded through a namespace.
     *
     * Prototype:
     *```
     *   $classmap = [
     *       'MyClass'   => '/path/to/class/file.php'
     *   ];
     *```
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    public $classmap = [];

    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Files
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * The files array provides a list of paths to __non-class__ files
     * that will be autoloaded. This can be useful for bootstrap operations
     * or for loading functions.
     *
     * Prototype:
     * ```
     *    $files = [
     *         '/path/to/my/file.php',
     *    ];
     * ```
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    public $files = [];
}
````

this is my migration
path file =Modules\Common\Database\Migrations\Settting

```
<?php namespace Modules\Common\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class Setting extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        //

        /*
        * Setting
        */
        $this->forge->addField([
            'id' => ['type' => 'int', 'constraint' => 11, 'unsigned' => true, 'auto_increment' => true],
            'key' => ['type' => 'varchar', 'constraint' => 255],
            'value' => ['type' => 'varchar', 'constraint' => 255],
            'description' => ['type' => 'varchar', 'constraint' => 300],
            'status' => ['type' => 'tinyint', 'constraint' => 1, 'null' => 0, 'default' => 1],
            'created_at' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
            'updated_at' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
            'deleted_at' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
        ]);

        $this->forge->addKey('id', true);
        $this->forge->addUniqueKey('key');
        $this->forge->createTable('setting', true);

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function down()
    {
        // drop constraints first to prevent errors
       

        $this->forge->dropTable('setting', true);
    }
}
```

to call it

```
 php spark migrate  setting -n 'Module\Common'
```

for more info go there

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/migration.html

Comment: That is basically incorrect. The [`migrate` command has no *argument* definition](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/3ddc3c3e4840dbf366700cc0455e1379b17437d7/system/Commands/Database/Migrate.php#L58). Meaning that you **can't** pass a specific migration *'class name/file path'* as the first argument. It **only** supports `-n , -g , --n` options.

Comment: Your command *`php spark migrate  setting -n 'Module\Common'`* will essentially [*locate and run all new migrations against the database in the namespace `Module\Common `*](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/3ddc3c3e4840dbf366700cc0455e1379b17437d7/system/Commands/Database/Migrate.php#L44). This isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: Its working for me  this is only way trust me